Create a labelling vector for ggplot2 out of a single string
I have a vector (dataframe column, ....) like
labels  <- c("127_500", "128_500","13_200")

I would like to create a vector which reads like this:
new vector <-  c("127_500" = "500",  
                 "128_500" = "500",
                 "131_200" = "200")

So, i basically split the original split at "_" and keep the 2nd part and create something like a named vector:
> new_vector
127_500 128_500 131_200 
  "500"   "500"   "200" 

Is this possible?
I need to use new_vector as a labelling information in scale_x_discrete in ggplot. I have several hundred input strings.

new_vector = sub(".*_", "", labels) |> setNames(labels)?

Solutions without using regular expression:
setNames(sapply(strsplit(labels, '_'), `[`, 2), labels)
# 127_500 128_500  13_200 
#   "500"   "500"   "200"

setNames(stringr::word(labels, 2, sep = '_'), labels)
# 127_500 128_500  13_200 
#   "500"   "500"   "200"

setNames(stringr::str_split_i(labels, '_', i = 2), labels)
# 127_500 128_500  13_200 
#   "500"   "500"   "200"

